# Joining two pthreads via pthread_join() doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm creating two different `pthread`s via `pthread_create()` and wait for them to exit by calling `pthread_join()`.

When I run the program, the last output is "Waiting for thread1 to finish...", so it actually stops when trying to join the first thread and then terminates.

When I only create and run one thread and wait for its execution to be finished by using `pthread_join()`, everything works fine and the output is as expected.

What am I missing here? I already searched the web and figured out that `pthread_join()` doesn't behave as usual when creating more than one thread. But how do I actually use it in order to wait for finishing the execution of two `pthread`s?

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct
{
  double speed_in_kmh;
  double current_power_in_mega_watts;
} DeLorean;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int* cap_indices;
  unsigned int array_length;
} IndexContainer;

typedef struct {
  unsigned char* c_string;
  unsigned int value;
} FluxCapacitor;

DeLorean* delorean__;
FluxCapacitor** capacitors__;

pthread_mutex_t lock;

// Thread function.
void* assembleDeLorean(void* indices)
{
    // Get mutex to lock function and make sure
    // that only one thread at a time is using it.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);


    // Declare "indices" parameter as IndexContainer.
    IndexContainer* iC = indices;

    double sum = 0;

    // Iterate through all given indices in iC
    // and add value of iC to sum, if index exists.
    for (int i = 0; i < 121; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < iC->array_length; ++j)
        {
            if (i == iC->cap_indices[j])
            {
                sum += capacitors__[i]->value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Assign computed sum to power of global delorean.
    delorean__->current_power_in_mega_watts = sum;

    // Release mutex.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    // Stop thread.
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Main thread \"main()\" was started.\n");

    capacitors__ = createFluxCapacitorArray(121);
    delorean__ = createDeLorean(0, 0);

    IndexContainer* iC_1 = malloc(sizeof(*iC_1));
    iC_1->array_length = 21;
    iC_1->cap_indices = malloc(21 * sizeof(unsigned int));

    IndexContainer* iC_2 = malloc(sizeof(*iC_2));
    iC_2->array_length = 100;
    iC_2->cap_indices = malloc(100 * sizeof(unsigned int));

    // Fill iC_1.
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
    {
        iC_1->cap_indices[i] = i;
    }

    // Fill iC_2.
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 21; i < 121; ++i)
    {
        iC_2->cap_indices[k] = i;
        ++k;
    }

    // Declare threads.
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int rT1, rT2;

    // Initialize mutex protecting "assembleDeLorean" function.
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    // Create & run first thread.
    printf("Creating and running thread1.\n");
    rT1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, assembleDeLorean, &iC_1);
    if (rT1 != 0)
    {
        printf("Thread 1 could not be created.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Return value of creation of thread1: %d\n", rT1);


    // Create & run second thread.
    printf("Creating and running thread2.\n");
    rT2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, assembleDeLorean, &iC_2);
    if (rT2 != 0)
    {
        printf("Thread 2 could not be created.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Return value of creation of thread2: %d\n", rT2);   

    // Wait for threads to finish.
    printf("Waiting for thread1 to finish...\n");
    if (pthread_join(thread1, NULL))
    {
        printf("An error occured while joining thread1.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Thread1 finished!");


    printf("Waiting for thread2 to finish...\n");
    if (pthread_join(thread2, NULL))
    {
        printf("An error occured while joining thread2.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Thread2 finished!");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Does it not print "An error occured while joining thread1." ?

Comment: @Pras No, it doesn't. It just stops when executing this function and doesn't even get into the statement block of the if condition...

Comment: @PeteHilde That means that the thread you labeled as *thread 1* has not finished yet.

Comment: pthread_join() works as it's supposed to, so the error is elswhere. Do your program actually terminate ? Or does it hang ? Or does it crash ? I suggest you also run your program thorough the valgrind tool, it will tell you if there's any obvious errors when running your program

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yeah, logically this is correct. But I don't get why.. Inside `assembleDeLorean()` I call `pthread_exit()` so the thread should exit properly... Moreover, the loop is executed correctly, I already figured that out withou using threads...

Comment: @nos Yes, it terminates properly, I get a message in the console telling me `<terminated>`. It doesn't crash. How do I get this tool and how do I use it?

Comment: try pstack pid, it should print stacktrace of your threads

Comment: @PeteHilde Why do you need to call `pthread_exit()` at all? "*Moreover, the loop is executed correctly, I already figured that out withou using threads...*" testing a program by running it doesn't prove it's correct, specially when there exists undefined behavior like in the [tag:c] programming language. I suggest using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to test both, memory access and thread synchronicity. Because there might be a problem deeply hidden in your logic that causes a behavior that you can't actually predict or test.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This entails adding some code so that the thing builds, and then removing most of the code so that there's minimal amount of code but the error is still the original error.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi To terminate the calling thread because that is what it's supposed to do when the loop is finished.

Comment: @PeteHilde I don't think you should draw the conclusion that a message of `<terminated>` means your program exited cleanly. Though I don't know what OS you're using, or what kind of application prints that messge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing incorrect arguments to your pthread_create() functions.

```
rT2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, assembleDeLorean, &iC_2);
rT1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, assembleDeLorean, &iC_1);
```

should be

```
rT2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, assembleDeLorean, iC_2);
rT1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, assembleDeLorean, iC_1);
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. It works! Thanks! Why do I actually need to pass it like this?

Comment: `iC_1` and `iC_2` are already pointers to `IndexContainer`